# how to get running jar file name from system in java

Tags: java, windows, jar

I have a jar named `helloDemo`. I have double clicked on the jar file to run, assume it is running now. Now in another program I want to get all the jar file names and print them which are currently running or active in my system (windows7). Is there any way to do it ? I have goggled for it but no luck. Can anybody please help me on this ?

Comment: What operating system are you using? In what application did you double-click the jar files?

Comment: windows 7, just on distributed jar

Comment: Well, you should see the corresponding java.exe process in the task manager, AFAICT. However, if you need to get the list in some programe, then you should enumerate these processes and system scripting facilities are quite limited under Windows.

Comment: can you give some code example please

Comment: Well, I dont have Window 7, sorry.

Comment: doesn't matter, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can list all Java processes on the local machine or a remote machine with using Java Virtual Machine Process Status Tool - `jps`:

`jps [options] [hostid]`

- `options` - list of options
- `hostid` - host identifier of the remote machine.

For more information:

- [jps - Java Virtual Machine Process Status Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have successfully created a runnable jar, and not a simple archive, (if you're not sure about that, this question might be helpful: [How to make an executable jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file)) and `HelloDemo.java` looks like the further code (or something more elaborate) to ensure it will run a long time.

```
public class HelloDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    while(true);
  }
}
```

Ok, this one runs a *very* long time ;P

So, you're able to launch a bunch of java process, and now want to list them. Well, stackoverflow is all you need:

- [How to get a list of current open windows process with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java)
- [List of Java processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283167/list-of-java-processes) which is a linux-specific answer
- [Aleksey Bybov's answer about `jps`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30001214/1498389)